# React Change Navbar title based on rendered page

Tags: reactjs

I have this BrowserRouter component as my top level component with a title string in its state. This component renders a NavigationComponent which is basically a nav bar, in there i would like to set a title which changes depending on where i go on the site.

The component looks roughly like this

```
  changeTitle(title) {
    this.setState({
      title: title,
    })
  }

  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <NavigationComponent title={this.state.title}/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => (
          <App {...props} changeTitle= {this.changeTitle.bind(this)}/>
        )} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent }/>
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={LoginComponent }/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Now i know how to expose the method `changeTitle` to the App Component. 
But i'd like to expose the method further and the way i've implemented it atm is this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  changeTitle(title) {
    this.props.changeTitle(title);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <OverviewComponent changeTitle= {this.changeTitle.bind(this)}/>
  }
} // note: App component stripped down
```

In the Overviewcomponent is the first time i actually call the changeTitle function.

My Question is now: is there a more clever way to implement this without piping the method changeTitle to every child? There are many more components which are called after the OverviewComponent and those need to change the title too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your NavigationComponent, I think it would make more sense to have an event-listener that would check for whenever you navigated to another page.
It looks like you're already using `react-router-dom`, so this is perfect.

You need to wrap your component with the `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom`. This will give us access to the `history` prop, which has an event listener method. We can create that event-listener in componentDidMount() so its always active.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

class NavigationComponent extends React.Component{
   state = {
      title: "Home"
   }

   changeTitle = (newTitle) => {
      this.setState({
          title: newTitle
      })
   }

   componentDidMount(){
    //listens for any route changes
    this.props.history.listen(() => {
        this.changeTitle(window.location.pathname) <-- this can be whatever value you want.
    })
   }

   render(){
      <div>{this.state.title}</div>
   }
}

export default withRouter(NavigationComponent)
```

This seems to be alot more intuitive than having to pass in values from another component.

Comment: @Pio I just came to the realization that this probably might no work. But i have a better solution for you. Are you currently testing this?

Comment: yeah trying to, haven't make it work yet. I'm trying to define a custom event which i raise in the didmount function of the overviewcomponent

Comment: Just updated my solution. That should make it work. With that, I'm not sure you really need an overview component. Is the overview component just there to pass a title value to the navbar?

Comment: my application consists of many modules that fullfill different requirements. The overview component will display all the available moduls and let the user navigate to them. Overviewcomp title will be "overview". when navigating to modul1 the title will change and extended further from there. i.e. "modul1 - dashboard - project1..."

Comment: The complexity of your application is far more vast than I expected. I wish you good luck! In any case, I think what I wrote above should suffice for whenever you want to display a new title on your navbar on route-change.

Comment: yeah it is :D i will accept your answer because it brought me on a good track that.

Answer (score 1):

Check `window.location.pathname` and make pathname as Navbar title

```
// Navbar.js
changeTitle = () => {
  switch(window.location.pathname){
    case '/profile':
      return 'Profile';
    case '/admin':
      return 'Admin';
    default:
      return 'Dashboard';
  }
}
render(){
 let title = changeTitle();
  return(<div>{title}</div>)
}
```

Comment: sounds promising, but a i think the deeper my path gets the more i will have to manage this method and extend it, the idea of christopher sounds easier to implement to me. but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Pio `pathname='/questions/101/react-change/213'`. Then, title = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] will assign `questions`